# PHP Composer package credentials

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a PHP package which I include to a larger application as a Composer package.

The code connects to an API to retrieve and send data.

What are some options to store the API credentials? Bearing in mind the application can be used across multiple environments each with potentially different API credentials i.e. staging, production.

And that I do not want to store credentials in the Git repo.

Options:

1. Environment variables
2. Uncomitted config file which is manually created on each environment
3. This is where I run out of ideas

Comment: You can commit a config-dist file which stores just a list of configuration parameters with a default value. The user can then rename it and edit it after the installation. You can even automate this process with [composer's installer event](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#installer-events), where you can ask the user the credentials when they install/update with composer, so that you can auto-generate the config file.

Comment: you can take a look at this package: https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler

Answer (score 0):

It should not be the task of the API client package to deal with accessing credentials. The only way for that client to obtain them should be through a class method as parameters.

This can come in several flavours:

```
$client = new ApiClient($location, $user, $password);
$client = ApiClientFactory::getInstance($location, $user, $password);
...
```

Note that creating an instance of the API client is part of the packages' interface, so it should exist, be documented, and not be changed incompatibly in minor updates.

Providing the credentials is the task of the application using this package.